# How do I monitor net traffic for a given application using .net?

Tags: .net, network-programming, network-traffic

How can I monitor the network traffic for a given app using .net?

UPDATE: How can I monitor the network traffic of another application using .net?

Comment: Your own app, or another app?

Comment: Also, what kind of platform? ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC, WCF, ...

Comment: Just monitor the usage/speed or the entire protocol?

Comment: Both Microsoft Network Monitor and Process Monitor from SysInternals allow you to look at network traffic per-application.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to the code for the application, you might be able to do it with an Aspect-Oriented Framework that does [runtime weaving.](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/aop.net/runtime-weaving)

Runtime weaving allows you to modify the executable so that it calls your monitoring code *before* the networking code in the application.